# Stack too deep exception

Tags: solidity, compilation

I get this error when i try to compile my code:

```
Internal compiler error: Stack too deep, try removing local variables.
```

How could i get around this issue, I though the stack could be at least 16 level deep ? How is mine too deep ?!

```
contract ZonesFactory {
    address[] zones;
    event LogCreatedZone(address indexed hsAddr, string name, string P1Lon, string P1Lat, string P2Lon, string P2Lat, string P3Lon, string P3Lat, string P4Lon, string P4Lat);

    function add(string name, string P1Lon, string P1Lat, string P2Lon, string P2Lat, string P3Lon, string P3Lat, string P4Lon, string P4Lat) public returns(address) {
        zoneObject newZone = new zoneObject(name, P1Lon, P1Lat, P2Lon, P2Lat, P3Lon, P3Lat, P4Lon, P3Lat);
        zones.push(newZone);
        LogCreatedZone(newZone,name, P1Lon, P1Lat, P2Lon, P2Lat, P3Lon, P3Lat, P4Lon, P3Lat);
        return newZone;
    }

    function getOrgAtIndex(uint index) public constant returns(address org){
        return zones[index];
    }

    function getOrganizationCount() public constant returns(uint count) {
        return zones.length;
    }
}

contract zoneObject {

    struct LonLat {
        string P1Lon;
        string P1Lat;
        string P2Lon; 
        string P2Lat; 
        string P3Lon; 
        string P3Lat; 
        string P4Lon; 
        string P4Lat;
    }

    LonLat public lonLat;

    string public name;

    function zoneObject (string name, string P1Lon, string P1Lat, string P2Lon, string P2Lat, string P3Lon, string P3Lat, string P4Lon, string P4Lat){
        name = name;
        lonLat.P1Lon = P1Lon;
        lonLat.P1Lat = P1Lat;
        lonLat.P2Lon = P2Lon;
        lonLat.P2Lat = P1Lat;
        lonLat.P3Lon = P3Lon;
        lonLat.P3Lat = P3Lat;
        lonLat.P4Lon = P4Lon;
        lonLat.P4Lat = P4Lat;
    }

    function getDetails() public constant returns (string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string){
        return (name, lonLat.P1Lon, lonLat.P1Lat, lonLat.P2Lon, lonLat.P2Lat, lonLat.P3Lon, lonLat.P3Lat, lonLat.P4Lon, lonLat.P4Lat);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have tried with the following code thinking that makin my points into a seperact contract would help but it just doesn't, please help:

```
contract ZonesFactory {
    address[] zones;
    event LogCreatedZone(address indexed hsAddr, string name, string P1Lon, string P1Lat, string P2Lon, string P2Lat, string P3Lon, string P3Lat, string P4Lon, string P4Lat);

    function add(string name, string P1Lon, string P1Lat, string P2Lon, string P2Lat, string P3Lon, string P3Lat, string P4Lon, string P4Lat) public returns(address) {
        zoneObject newZone = new zoneObject(name, P1Lon, P1Lat, P2Lon, P2Lat, P3Lon, P3Lat, P4Lon, P3Lat);
        zones.push(newZone);
        LogCreatedZone(newZone,name, P1Lon, P1Lat, P2Lon, P2Lat, P3Lon, P3Lat, P4Lon, P3Lat);
        return newZone;
    }

    function getOrgAtIndex(uint index) public constant returns(address org){
        return zones[index];
    }

    function getOrganizationCount() public constant returns(uint count) {
        return zones.length;
    }
}

contract zoneObject {

    struct PointCoords {
        pointObject P1Coords;
        pointObject P2Coords; 
        pointObject P3Coords; 
        pointObject P4Coords; 
    }

    PointCoords public pointsCoords;
    address[] public patients;
    string public name;

    function zoneObject (string name, string P1Lon, string P1Lat, string P2Lon, string P2Lat, string P3Lon, string P3Lat, string P4Lon, string P4Lat){
        name = name;
        pointsCoords.P1Coords = new pointObject(P1Lon, P1Lat);
        pointsCoords.P2Coords = new pointObject(P2Lon, P2Lat);
        pointsCoords.P3Coords = new pointObject(P3Lon, P3Lat);
        pointsCoords.P4Coords = new pointObject(P4Lon, P4Lat);
    }

    function addPatient(address patientAddress){
        patients.push(patientAddress);
    }

    function getDetails() public constant returns (string, address, address, address, address){
        return (name, pointsCoords.P1Coords pointsCoords.P2Coords, pointsCoords.P3Coords, pointsCoords.P4Coords);
    }

    function removePatient(address patient){
        if(isContract(patient)){
            for (uint i = 0; i<patients.length-1; i++){
                if(patients[i] == patient){
                    delete patients[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function isContract(address addr) returns (bool) {
        uint size;
        assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
        return size > 0;
    }
}

contract pointObject{
    string public Lat;
    string public Lon;

    function pointObject (string Lon, string Lat){
        Lat = Lat;
        Lon = Lon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't waded through all the code but the widespread use of `string` in the interface stood out, so I tried replacing them all with `bytes32` and got a successful compile right away.

```
contract ZonesFactory {
    address[] zones;
    event LogCreatedZone(address indexed hsAddr, bytes32 name, bytes32 P1Lon, bytes32 P1Lat, bytes32 P2Lon, bytes32 P2Lat, bytes32 P3Lon, bytes32 P3Lat, bytes32 P4Lon, bytes32 P4Lat);

    function add(bytes32 name, bytes32 P1Lon, bytes32 P1Lat, bytes32 P2Lon, bytes32 P2Lat, bytes32 P3Lon, bytes32 P3Lat, bytes32 P4Lon, bytes32 P4Lat) public returns(address) {
        zoneObject newZone = new zoneObject(name, P1Lon, P1Lat, P2Lon, P2Lat, P3Lon, P3Lat, P4Lon, P3Lat);
        zones.push(newZone);
        LogCreatedZone(newZone,name, P1Lon, P1Lat, P2Lon, P2Lat, P3Lon, P3Lat, P4Lon, P3Lat);
        return newZone;
    }

    function getOrgAtIndex(uint index) public constant returns(address org){
        return zones[index];
    }

    function getOrganizationCount() public constant returns(uint count) {
        return zones.length;
    }
}

contract zoneObject {

    struct LonLat {
        bytes32 P1Lon;
        bytes32 P1Lat;
        bytes32 P2Lon; 
        bytes32 P2Lat; 
        bytes32 P3Lon; 
        bytes32 P3Lat; 
        bytes32 P4Lon; 
        bytes32 P4Lat;
    }

    LonLat public lonLat;

    bytes32 public name;

    function zoneObject (bytes32 name, bytes32 P1Lon, bytes32 P1Lat, bytes32 P2Lon, bytes32 P2Lat, bytes32 P3Lon, bytes32 P3Lat, bytes32 P4Lon, bytes32 P4Lat){
        name = name;
        lonLat.P1Lon = P1Lon;
        lonLat.P1Lat = P1Lat;
        lonLat.P2Lon = P2Lon;
        lonLat.P2Lat = P1Lat;
        lonLat.P3Lon = P3Lon;
        lonLat.P3Lat = P3Lat;
        lonLat.P4Lon = P4Lon;
        lonLat.P4Lat = P4Lat;
    }

    function getDetails() public constant returns (bytes32, bytes32, bytes32, bytes32, bytes32, bytes32, bytes32, bytes32, bytes32){
        return (name, lonLat.P1Lon, lonLat.P1Lat, lonLat.P2Lon, lonLat.P2Lat, lonLat.P3Lon, lonLat.P3Lat, lonLat.P4Lon, lonLat.P4Lat);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.